# How to save certificate filename in index file with Openssl ca

Tags: openssl

I am signing certificates with the command **openssl ca** and it automatically stores the information in the index file. As this [webpage](https://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cadb.html) sais, in the index file the 5th column is the *Certificate filename or literal string ‘unknown'*, and in my case all certificates are saved as 'unknown'. How can I save the filename (certificate filename or csr filename) in that column?